# Where can I find information about this concept of 'dual ideals'?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, forcing, descriptive-set-theory, cardinal-characteristics

I have come across the following notion of (what I am calling) dual ideals, and I am looking for any work in which this notion has been considered, and particularly anything about transferring properties of the ideals.

**Definition.** Let $R\subseteq X\times Y$ be a relation on two sets $X$ and $Y$ such that for all $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$, both $R_x=\{y\in Y\mid\langle x,y\rangle\in R\}$ and $R^y=\{x\in X\mid\langle x,y\rangle\in R\}$ are nonempty. Define the $\sigma$-ideal $I_R$ on $X$ as being $\sigma$-generated by sets of the form $R^y$ as $y$ ranges over $Y$, and the $\sigma$-ideal $J_R$ on $Y$ as being $\sigma$-generated by the *complements* of sets of the form $R_x$ as $x$ ranges over $X$.

**Remark.** If $I_R$ is a proper ideal (contains all singletons, and $X\notin I_R$), and for all $H\in[X]^\omega$ there is $y\in Y$ such that $R^y\supseteq H$ (e.g. if $I_R$ is generated by the $R^y$, not just $\sigma$-generated) then $J_R$ will be proper as well.

**Example.** A set $A\subseteq2^\omega$ is meagre if and only if there is a chopped real $(x,\Pi)$ that no member of $A$ matches, so if $R=\{\langle a,(x,\Pi)\rangle\mid a$ does not match $(x,\Pi)\}$, then $I_R$ will be the meagre ideal, and $J_R$ will be some proper ideal on the set of chopped reals $\sigma$-generated by sets of the form $\{(x,\Pi)\mid a$ matches $(x,\Pi)\}$ for $a\in2^\omega$.

**Questions.** Where can I find a treatment of ideals of this form? In particular, I am wondering if any tameness (in the descriptive set theory sense) properties of the ideal $I_R$ will transfer to $J_R$. For example, if we demand that both $X$ and $Y$ are Polish spaces, and that for all $x,y$, $R$, $R_x$, and $R^y$ are Borel, then if $I_R$ is $\Pi^1_1$ on $\Sigma^1_1$, will $J_R$ be as well?

These dual ideals have a clear relationship with the duals of Galois-Turkey relations as seen in, for example, Blass's work, and seem to be connected to preservation theorems for cardinal characteristics under idealized forcing as seen in, for example, Zapletal's work.

*Blass, Andreas*, [**Combinatorial cardinal characteristics of the continuum**](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4020-5764-9_7), Foreman, Matthew (ed.) et al., Handbook of set theory. In 3 volumes. Dordrecht: Springer (ISBN 978-1-4020-4843-2/hbk; 978-1-4020-5764-9/ebook). 395-489 (2010). [ZBL1198.03058](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1198.03058).

*Zapletal, Jindřich*, Forcing idealized, Cambridge Tracts in Mathematics 174. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press (ISBN 978-0-521-87426-7/hbk). 314 p. (2008). [ZBL1140.03030](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1140.03030).

Comment: This appears to be a notion known to Ulam (2nd paragraph of [Mycielski 1969](https://eudml.org/doc/263142); also Ulam's student Mendez [1](https://doi.org/10.2307/2041125) & [2](https://doi.org/10.2307/2042560)) & considered in [Wagon 1980](https://doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1980-007-9) & [Cichon/Kamburelis/Pawlikowski 1985](https://doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1980-007-9) (see p. 144) & [Cichon/Pawlikowski 1986](https://doi.org/10.2307/2274013) & [Gavalec 1985](https://eudml.org/doc/265432) & [Balcerzak 1989](https://eudml.org/doc/196823) & [Balcerzak 1988](https://bibliotekanauki.pl/issues/35471).

Comment: Possibly useful for this and other related notions is Balcerzak's 1991 Habilitation thesis [**Some Properties of Ideals of Sets in Polish Spaces**](https://www.worldcat.org/title/38963544). I don't know if a copy can be found on the internet (or even if he has a scan of it), but I made a .pdf scan of it a few years ago [if you're interested](https://mathoverflow.net/users/15780/dave-l-renfro?tab=profile).

Comment: "Dual ideal" might be confusing terminology, as it has been used in the literature to mean "filter".